# code is not waiting for forEach to complete : Async

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have a function

```
transformAllUser = async (userList): Promise<any> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const userListArray = [];
        userList.forEach((user) => { 
             // do something like or something else
            userListArray.push({obj : user})
        })
     resolve(userListArray )
 })
}
```

and to get that value:

```
const val = await transformAllUser(userList);
console.log(val) // its empty.
```

I am getting an empty array, What am I doing wrong here so that my code is not waiting for `forEach` to complete

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown us explains the behaviour you are seeing. Maybe `const val = await transformAllUserAndSubscription (userList)` isn't in an async function.

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown us explains the behaviour you are seeing. Maybe `const val = await transformAllUserAndSubscription (userList)` isn't in an async function. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @jhc — It's looping over `userList` not `userListArray`, we can't see what value it has.

Comment: @Quentin Apologies. Fixed function name

Comment: @Samuel Show us the value of userList.

Comment: Why  downvotes ? :(

Comment: You cannot await for an async function rather await inside an async function.

Comment: @jhc does it matter. it's some array of length 1000 and I want to iterate over it and fill some other array and then return that `other` array (userListArray )

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar — You can await only promises. async functions always return promises. That much is fine.

Comment: @Quentin thanks. I was always using await inside an async function but not outside. Glad to know this.

Comment: @Samuel. Quentin is correct. You can only use await, inside an async function. Also, nothing in transformAllUser actually needs to be asynchronous. Honestly the promise itself is overkill.

Comment: @jhc : `transformAllUser` is being called by some other function. so it has to be async.

Comment: I believe I've seen the answer to this before - it's something to do with `forEach` treating each iteration as an individual method and not necessarily a sequential set of instructions to be carried out like in, say, a traditional `for` loop with a starting index and an end index. Still trying to find exactly where I read this information and will post a link.

Comment: From what I remember, using `for (user of userList)` instead is the correct solution to this.

Comment: @AJC24 — It depends on what is being done inside the loop. The OP needs to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `async` `await` for this. If the code inside your for loop is not going to make any asynchronous operation, you wouldn't need to use `async` `await`.

Something simple like this should work for you.

```js
const transformAllUser = (userList) => {
  const userListArray = [];
  userList.forEach((user) => {
    userListArray.push({
      obj: user
    })
  })
  return userListArray;
}

const userList = [{name: 'john'}, {name: 'doe'}];
const val = transformAllUser(userList);
console.log(val);
```

If you still want to use `async` `await`, then you need to use it the right way. `await` can exist only inside an `async` function.

```js
const transformAllUser = async (userList) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const userListArray = [];
    userList.forEach((user) => {
      userListArray.push({ obj: user })
      // if you have any asyncronous actions here, say, API call or promise, you will await it
      // await makeAsyncCall()
    })
    resolve(userListArray);
  })

}

const userList = [{
  name: 'john'
}, {
  name: 'doe'
}];

transformAllUser(userList).then(val => {
  console.log(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that you could use.

```js
const transformAllUser = async (userList) => userList.map(user => ({obj: user}))
const users = [{name : "1"}, {name : "2"}, {name : "3"}]

(async () => {
  const transformedUsers = await transformAllUser(users)
  console.log(transformedUsers)
})()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Use async node module.

let async = require('async');

function transformAllUser(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      async.eachOfSeries(userList, (user, callback)=>{
      // do something like or something else
      callback(null, {obj : user});
}, (err, results)=>{
   if(err){
      // Handle error
      reject(err);
   } else {
      resolve(results);
   }
})
   });
}
```